# How do I add a page featured image to nivo slider in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider

I've followed the guide below in trying to manually install nivo slider into Wordpress: http://www.aoclarkejr.com/author/aj/

I'm trying to get the slider to pick up and display the featured image. I think perhaps there is a problem with the code in step 6, and not just the missing ' (see below). As the slider appears to be loading i.e I get the next/prev tabs and can see the code when viewing the page source, but it's not picking up and displaying the featured image.

```
 <div id="slider-wrap">
    <div id="slider">
    <?php query_posts(array(
    'post_type'=>'slides
    ));
    ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
?>
<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" width="" height="" />
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--/slider nivoSlider-->
</div><!--/slider-wrap -->
```

I should add that I'm trying to get this to work on a page, not custom post.
My ultimate goal is the get the same implementation as this: http://pexetothemes.com/demos/story_wp/home-default/

Here is my code now:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="header-wrapper">
<div id="slider-wrap">
<div id="slider">
<?php query_posts(array(
'post_type'=>'page'
));
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
?> <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" width="" height="" /> 
<?php // endwhile; ?>
</div><!--/slider nivoSlider-->
</div><!--/slider-wrap -->


</div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div id="content-container" class="content-boxed layout-full">
            <div id="full-width" class="content">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <?php the_content(); ?> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- page wrapper --> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For some reason part of the page is repeating itself.

```
       <div class="header-wrapper"></div>
        <div id="slider-wrap">
            <div id="slider">
                <img width="" height="" src="http://localhost:8888/defylife/assets/images/posts/ccm_adventure_450gp_left.jpg"></img>
            </div>
            <!--

            /slider nivoSlider

            -->
        </div>
        <!--

        /slider-wrap 

        -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="content-container" class="content-boxed layout-full">
            <div id="full-width" class="content">
                <div class="content-box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img width="" height="" src=""></img>
    </div>
    <!--

    /slider nivoSlider

    -->

</div>
<!--

/slider-wrap 

-->
```

Comment: If you are not using a custom post type then shouldn't you change 'slides' to 'post' above? It looks to me like you are trying to find posts of the type 'slides' and get the image for that.

Comment: Ah yes post_type needs to be 'page'

Comment: It almost works except the image keeps repeating itself down the page.